# How to implement own Storage backends for Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to save crawl result into `redis` by feed export way.

So, how to implement own Storage backends for `Scrapy`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save crawled items into `redis` I suggest you use [scrapy redis](https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-redis) and the `RedisPipeline`.

For other database you should use custom `Pipeline`. I'll let you check the [scrapy doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb) and the `MongoDB` exemple.